# infinite loop shutting down ensime

Tags: emacs, scala, ensime

When I run M-X ensime-disconnect I get the following forever:

```
string matching regex `\"((?:[^\"\\]|\\.)*)\"' expected but `^@' found
```

and I see this exception when I use C-c C-c

```
Uncaught exception in com.ensime.server.SocketHandler@769aba32
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:220)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:290)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:294)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:140)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:253)
    at com.ensime.server.SocketHandler.write(server.scala:118)
    at com.ensime.server.SocketHandler$$anonfun$act$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(server.scala:132)
    at com.ensime.server.SocketHandler$$anonfun$act$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(server.scala:127)
    at scala.actors.Actor$class.receive(Actor.scala:456)
    at com.ensime.server.SocketHandler.receive(server.scala:67)
    at com.ensime.server.SocketHandler$$anonfun$act$1.apply$mcV$sp(server.scala:127)
    at com.ensime.server.SocketHandler$$anonfun$act$1.apply(server.scala:127)
    at com.ensime.server.SocketHandler$$anonfun$act$1.apply(server.scala:127)
    at scala.actors.Reactor$class.seq(Reactor.scala:262)
    at com.ensime.server.SocketHandler.seq(server.scala:67)
    at scala.actors.Reactor$$anon$3.andThen(Reactor.scala:240)
    at scala.actors.Combinators$class.loop(Combinators.scala:26)
    at com.ensime.server.SocketHandler.loop(server.scala:67)
    at scala.actors.Combinators$$anonfun$loop$1.apply(Combinators.scala:26)
    at scala.actors.Combinators$$anonfun$loop$1.apply(Combinators.scala:26)
    at scala.actors.Reactor$$anonfun$seq$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Reactor.scala:259)
    at scala.actors.ReactorTask.run(ReactorTask.scala:36)
    at scala.actors.ReactorTask.compute(ReactorTask.scala:74)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:147)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.quietlyExec(ForkJoinTask.java:422)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.mainLoop(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:340)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:325)
```

Is there something else I'm missing in my config or I should check on?

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 4):

This is a known bug which (now) has an open issue on github.
Thanks for the report.

-Aemon

**Update**

This problem is fixed in the latest version (>= 0.0.5): http://github.com/aemoncannon/ensime/downloads